# "No Such device" when trying to download any torrent on deluge inside docker container

Tags: command-line, ssh, debian, deluge, mediaserver

I have a debian ssh media server based on this [article](https://www.linuxserver.io/blog/2017-06-24-the-perfect-media-server-2017), that has a complete setup of docker containers, that include Radarr, Sonarr and Plex. All the downloads are made through deluge, which was working fine until a few days ago, when torrents were no longer being downloaded. Every torrent started instantly goes into an "Error" mode. When I check the status on the bottom, it reads:
Status: No such device
I've tried restarting the system and the containers themselves, but nothing seems to work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar issue here. It appears to be an issue with linuxserver's latest deluge container - they did some replatforming in the container, but I did not take time to look into why this might break it.
In any case, I found that by rolling back to tag 2.0.5-0202202181752ubuntu20.04.1-ls140, deluge started working again. You can do this via docker compose by adding a colon (:) then the tag name to the end of the image name.

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you very much!